# UPDATE concat and variables

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I might just be sleepy, but i've tried to concat this in various ways and it just isn't working. the $friend_id is simply a string, and shouldn't be causing a problem as far as I know.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends =  CONCAT(friends,"$friend_id")  WHERE username = '$user_logged_in'") or die mysql_error());
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends = friends +" . ", " . "'$friend_id' WHERE username = '$user_logged_in'");
```

any ideas where im tripping up?

Comment: If you use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql_query, and do prepare/bind you don't ever have this problem.  They also avoid serious SQL injection vulnerabilities with using mysql_query like this.

Comment: I **really** hope `$friend_id` is escaped properly..

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: @NullPointer I realize this is off-topic, but where do you keep that properly-formatted reply?  I've seen that exact reply several times before.

Comment: @Daedalus lol.... this is same used by many users you can also get https://gist.github.com/3941118

Comment: @NullPointer Thank you for that; it's been bugging me for awhile.

Comment: @Daedalus yours very welcome .... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked in the end.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends = CONCAT(friends,'".",".$friend_id."') WHERE username = '$user_logged_in'");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends =  CONCAT(friends,'".$friend_id."')  WHERE username = '".$user_logged_in."'") or die mysql_error());
```

Comment: hmm, adds to db but doesnt concat with ","

Answer (score 0):

Use . to concat string in PHP.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends =  CONCAT(friends,".$friend_id.")  WHERE username = '$user_logged_in'") or die mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Before run the query please check your variable "$friend_id". I just trimmed ",".

```
$friend_id = trim($friend_id, ',');
```

Query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friends =  CONCAT(friends,'".$friend_id."')  WHERE username = '".$user_logged_in."'") or die mysql_error());
```