# How to concatenate and save first name and last name during INSERT using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to concatenate language and code as second query and save to database field litcode. 
This is my code

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO library (spot,code,language,count) values(?, ?, ?,?);UPDATE library SET litcode = CONCAT(language, code);";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count));
Database::disconnect();
```

Got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /home/booking/public_html/x/concat.php:46 Stack trace: #0 /home/booking/public_html/x/concat.php(46): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/booking/public_html/x/concat.php on line 5
```

This is line 5 in code `$q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count));`
How can I add the concatenated word litcode?

Comment: Please check out this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098371/update-concat-and-variables. marked answer

Comment: Why would you want to store duplicate data in your database? Apart from that the second query would update every single row in the database. You could do it in 1 statement binding 6 variables instead, but why would you want do that?

Comment: @jeroen, I want to save data like this in db. `spot code language count litcode` `Shelf1 TA English 29 TA-English` Need to sorting and count merge based on litcode in the end.

Comment: @jeroen  this is the merge code I'm planning to do in the end `'SELECT litcode, SUM(count) as count FROM library GROUP BY litcode'`
If I avoid saving litcode field, How to do the sum by merging 'language' and 'count'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code, you don't need `UPDATE` all the records when you only need `INSERT` the correct info, see this code:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO library (spot,code,language,count,litcode) values(?,?,?,?,CONCAT(language,code))";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count));
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian! Your code really worked, this saved lots of time and energy. :)

Comment: Now i'm trying to update the query. But the concate is not working. This is the code I tried.

`$pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE literatures  set spot = ?, code = ?,language = ?, count =?, litcode = CONCAT(language,'-',code) WHERE id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count,$litcode,$id));
            Database::disconnect();`

Comment: when I update the language or code, its not updating in the concatenated column. Previously entered concatenated value stays.

Comment: Browser is not throwing any error, After updating the language or code I see old concatenated string.

Comment: what you mean with 'old'? I think that you must open another question in this site with the problem

Comment: okay, I've create another question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668616/how-to-concatenate-two-string-during-mysql-update-query