# How to concatenate two string during MySQL UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, pdo

Use case: Created a record 
Spot, Code, Language, Count
...later found out language entered was wrong. Tried to change the language using UPDATE query. Concatenated string still show same. Updated language string not changed in the concatenated string.

Created  record using this MySql query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO library (spot,code,language,count,litcode) values(?,?,?,?,CONCAT(language,'-',code))";
```

Tried to UPDATE language using this MySql query

```
Database::connect(); $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$sql = "UPDATE literatures set spot = ?, code = ?,language = ?, count =?, litcode = CONCAT(language,'-',code) WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count,$litcode,$id)); 
Database::disconnect();
```

Finally language was updated but its not updating in the concatenated string.

Any errors in the UPDATE query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bind `$litcode` but you have `CONCAT(language,'-',code)`. You have 5 `?` in your query but you are trying to bind 6 params.

Change your code to this:

```
Database::connect(); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$sql = "UPDATE literatures set spot = ?, code = ?, language = ?, count = ?, litcode = ? WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$q->execute(array($spot,$code,$language,$count,$litcode,$id)); 
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Good catch. Alternately, just don't bind anything to litcode. Let it be concat(...). Corresponding to other 5 question marks, supply 5 relevant variables.

Comment: @zedfoxus thanks, maybe him don't want to bind 6 params, but the problem is in this place ;-)

Comment: @adrian-cid-almaguer
Thanks Adrian, Tried changing the code, still CONCAT not working
http://imageshack.com/a/img911/947/ucyLo6.png

Comment: @zedfoxus I tried like this earlier, $sql = "UPDATE literatures set spot = ?, code = ?,language = ?, count =?, litcode = CONCAT(language,'-',code) WHERE id = ?"; Is there any error in the concat code?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer See my screenshot. Initially I entered 'en' in language. But later changed to 'es', in the $litcode I was expecting 'es-new'. But old value continued to stay 'es-new'.

Comment: @Mcore8x I can't get the point, which value you want 'es-new'?

Comment: @Mcore8x can you print the value of $litcode and tell what you see?